# Как грамотно сделать scheduler на micropython?

Tags: micropython

Все (или почти все) примеры программ в итырнетах заканчиваются на while True:
Изначально мне мнилось что микроконтроллер не должен всей своей тактовой частотой гонять цикл по кругу. И, как выяснилось, если посмотреть [Программирование микроконтроллеров. Занятие 2](https://youtu.be/D-KhL0o9SQ4?t=3509) примерно с  58:30 то действительно я не первый кто пришел к такому выводу.

Для тех, кто видео не посмотрел. Задача минимум:

При опросе датчика DS18B20 мы должны дать ему пинка, подождать 750мс(смотри даташит) и только потом запрашивать показания. Кстати, эмпирическим путём установлено, что если подождать чуть дольше, то все работает.

Допустим каждые n минут(или часов, или дней) нам нужно отправлять данные куда-то. 
Также у нас может сработать прерывание потому что пользователь кнопку нажал. и нужно постоять поморгать циферблатом пока он(юзер) значения выбирает. А режим отправки сообщений нарушать нельзя. А это я ещё до всяких интернетов не добрался.
Вот как это грамотно женить между собой?

В простом Питоне [это уже реализовали](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/sched.py), если я правильно понял. Но моё кунг-фу ещё не так сильно, и мне кажется не все библиотеки есть на микропитоне.

Comment: Я управляю из Micropython-а шаговыми двигателями и уже столкнулся с тем, что таймер может только вызвать функцию. Если нужно только дёргать пин через равные промежутки, то всё более-менее, но малых задержках и когда нужно по ходу менять частоту таймера (скорость ШД), расцветают чудеса. Поэтому на малых промежутках я перешёл на sleep, но не теряю надежды научиться делать правильно.

Answer (score 0):

- Совсем короткие задержки, грубо говоря до 2 секунд (например, подождать 750 мс перед получением данных с датчика) лучше делать через `sleep`.
- Для более длинных задержек (несколько секунд - несколько минут) можно использовать
  таймер:
  [Timers](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/esp8266/quickref.html#timers)
- Для действий через длительные промежутки времени (десятки минут и более) можно попробовать использовать режим низкого энергопотребления (deep sleep mode) с пробуждением по сигналу от RTC (real-time clock - встроенных часов "реального" времени): [Deep-sleep
  mode](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/esp8266/quickref.html#deep-sleep-mode).

  Также можно сделать пробуждение при действии пользователя или вообще при внешнем воздействии: пробуждение происходит при сбросе платы, и пробуждение по сигналу от часов именно так и реализуется (для того, чтобы работало пробуждение по сигналу от часов, нужно соединить пин "будильника" с пином сброса).

  Также см. [MicroPython: ESP8266 Deep Sleep and Wake Up Sources](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/micropython-esp8266-deep-sleep-wake-up-sources/).

Вариант с режимом сна работает для ESP8266 и ESP32, но на каком-нибудь Pyboard (STM32) режима сна нет. Его можно его реализовать через внешний таймер (например, TPL5110), который будет включать/выключать питание платы.

Comment: О существовании всех этих функций поотдельности я знаю. Пока посмотрю что можно склепать на таймерах